# Imam's beliefs are doubtful

Tags: tawassul, imam-khatib

I am suspicious about **Imam's beliefs** regarding (Walee Ullah). His saying about pious people (Walee Ullah) is that they are closer to GOD. So ask them to pray for you instead pray directly. He put example that "my son is in bank and bank official will give more importance to my work if my son ask them to do that work, otherwise they will not listen to me". On Juma prayer he use to discuss minor contradictions in beliefs of "Deoband Followers" and "Bralli Followers" and make fun of "Deoband Followers", I want to know I am doubtful about his basic beliefs regarding GOD's "oneness" and about "Holly Prophet's Death" should I offer my prayer in his imam-at? Will Such prayer be accepted in front of GOD.
With answer please mention **reference**.

Comment: Would you please write your question more clearly? because it seems your question is a little vague. for instance: Who is "He" who gave you an example regarding Bank.. ?

Comment: He means "IMAM". Person who leads Prayer.

Comment: how can we be suspicious when the prophet (s) has mentioned to follow them? according to authentic sources, the prophet (s) ordered to follow Ahlul-Bayt..  so if i agree him, hence we ought to do his orders, oughtn't we?

Comment: @HELE-HELE we should follow them and we should respect them, but we can ask directly to GOD if we need anything. It is good to ask them for pray, but it is bad to say"GOD only listen to his Walee".God always listen to anyone either that person is walee or not.

Comment: Why down vote ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you said about Walee-Ullah and using him as a tool of nearness to God is mentioned in Quran:

> O you who have believed, fear Allah and seek the means [of nearness]
>   to Him and strive in His cause that you may succeed.
>   http://tanzil.net/#5:35

"Means [of nearness] to Him" means the tools that make nearness to God easier. One of best examples of means [of nearness] (Wasilah/Arabic: وسیله) that is mentioned in this verse is Walee Ullah. But please note Walee Ullah is not by claim. There are some cheaters who claim to be Walee Ullah to attract people to follow them. But they are nothing but cheater. Real Walee Ullah is very rare and difficult to find.

Walee Ullah is like a guide who guide people to reach to a goal easier.

Also in Quran we see Prophet Moses a.s. used prophet Khizr a.s. (who is alive now) as mean of nearness. Prophet Khizr is a Walee Ullah.

About acceptance of your prayers behind an Imam you should refer to required terms of an Imam of prayer. If he has the required terms of a prayer Imam then your prayer is accepted. Also you can easily talk him about your doubts and ask him to provide you proof and evidence from Quran and hadith and also please remember this warning of Quran:

> O you who have believed, avoid much [negative] assumption. Indeed,
>   some assumption is sin. And do not spy or backbite each other. Would
>   one of you like to eat the flesh of his brother when dead? You would
>   detest it. And fear Allah; indeed, Allah is Accepting of repentance
>   and Merciful. http://tanzil.net/#49:12

Comment: Hazrat Khizar is Prophet or Walee Ullah?

Comment: In question. I also asked about acceptance of prayer? If I am doubtful about Imam's beliefs will my prayer be accepted which offer in his immamt.

Comment: @UmarFarooq dear brother, I improved the answer. I hope it satisfy you.

Comment: @UmarFarooq he was both. prophet means who is takes messages of God to humans. and Walee Ullah means who is a close friend of God and has very close relation and high reputation with God.

Comment: I have a confusion. I want to know about Hazrat Khizar. What is his status? Was he prophet? if so then who is his predecessor and successor? Did Hazrat Khizar ever met Holly Prophet Muhammad.

Comment: @UmarFarooq I recommend you to ask it in a new question. comments are not suitable. but he alive still and does not need successor and he met prophet Muhamamd SAWW many times and asked his questions from him.